# Does launch4j work for all platforms?

Tags: java, launch4j

I have an application that has a few parts:

- A launcher
- The main data (the bin folder)

The main data will be in the form of a few executable jar files, and some other files. However, I want to make the launcher have some 'native' components to it.(A custom Icon, Version Info, etc.) I am going to use launch4j so I can write the launcher in java for portability, but still give it a native look. However, I do not know if launch4j can wrap executable jar files for the macintosh or linux platform.

So can I, a windows user, use launch4j to wrap my apps in native formats for other platforms?

If not, is there another jar file wrapper that will do this?

Comment: No launch4j is only for windows. I don't use other platform so I can't help you to find wrapper for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer: It can't. I will just wrap up my app in a icon.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OSX, you can use Oracle's appbundler: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html